# Run a command on a container from inside another one

Tags: docker

I'm trying to develop an application that has two main containers, a Java-Tomcat webserver and a Python and Lua one for machine learning scripts.

Soo here is the issue: I need to send a command on the Python/Lua container's CLI whenever the Java one receives a certain Request. I know that if the webserver wasn't a container I could simply use `docker exec`, but wouldn't having the Java part of my application as a non-container break the whole security idea of dockers?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Set up a REST API that allows one container to trigger actions on the other container?

Comment: But how can I do that from within a container to another one? I've built one to execute commands when I'm outside the container, doing it from one container to another seems like rocket science for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (+1 for @larsks) Set up a REST API that allows one container to trigger actions on the other container.
2. You can setup Container communication across links. Docs here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/
3. After that you can call from container A to B using `B:port/<your API>`

Comment: Thank you! Not only does this works, but it also seems like the most "docker-ish" solution.